# Web Service - CURL vs VS2008 vs SoapUI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, web-services, visual-studio-2008, curl

Using CURL... i was able to run the following command

```
 C:\curl>curl -H  "SOAPAction: http://172.16.255.7:5000/client_smart/"
 --data @soap.xml http://172.16.255.7:5000/client_smart
```

In my C:\ drive, i have a soap.xml file as defined here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <n1:get_client env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        xmlns:n1="urn:ActionWebService">
      <client_id xsi:type="xsd:int">1</client_id>
    </n1:get_client>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope
```

When I run the command, it executes as expected and information is returned.

---

---

However, when I open Visual Studio 2008, and try to add it as a reference, i get this message

```
 The document at the url http://172.16.255.7:5000/client_smart/wsdl was
 not recognized as a known document type. The error message from each
 known type may help you fix the problem:
 - Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Discovery document at the URL 
 http://172.16.255.7:5000/client_smart/wsdl could not
```

[image]

I've also tried it without the /wsdl in the URL for VS2008... but get "cannot display the page".

---

---

Using SoapUI for the URL, I get the message "Unable to determine namespace of 'action_web_service/xsd:string'"

Any idea as to why a web service would work in CURL, but not in VS2008 or SoapUI?

The service was developed in Ruby on Rails.